# How can I parse a YAML in python and output some of they keys to another YAML

Tags: python, pyyaml

I need  to read a YAML config file and then select some attributes and write to another YAML file.

Example:

```
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_host_slave: localhost
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: testdb
```

In this file I'd like to select only `database_host` and `database_name` fields. I can use:

```
config= yaml.load(file , Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
database_name = config['parameters']['database_name']
```

but that leaves me to manually write the output YAML to the file.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Did you check out `yaml.dump()` function? Is there a problem that `yaml.dump()` can't help?

Comment: The word attribute  is not used in the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) specification (and nor is atribute), so please specify exactly what you want as output YAML by editing your question. You should also consider using a more modern YAML library, PyYAML only supports YAML 1.1 and that was outdated ten years ago.

Comment: @Anthon What python Yaml library do you have in mind?